# Sirviendo imágenes como archivos estáticos en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un inconveniente con el despliegue de una imagen utilizando el `static` tag.

Tengo una clase llamada `ProfileView` que entra en acción cuando inicio sesión en mi formulario de login. Esta clase examina los datos del perfil del usuario que está por iniciar sesión y los muestra en su home, datos, como nombre, username, foto entre otros.

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.request.session['Hi'] = True
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        is_auth = False
        name = None
        #Pregunto si en el request va el user
        user = self.request.user

        #Indago sobre los posibles casos, falta hacer cuando un user sea paciente y medico
        if user.is_medical:
        #if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            print (user.is_medical)
            is_auth = True
            profile=user.get_medical_profile()
            #name = self.request.user.username

            data = {
                'is_auth':is_auth,
                'profile':profile,
            }

            context.update({'userprofile':profile, 'data':data})
        elif user.is_patient:
            print (user.is_patient)
            is_auth=True
            profile=user.get_patient_profile()

            data = {
                'is_auth':is_auth,
                'profile':profile,
            }
            context.update({'userprofile':profile,'data':data})
        elif user.is_physiotherapist:
            print (user.is_physiotherapist)
            is_auth=True
            profile=user.get_physiotherapist_profile()

            data = {
                'is_auth':is_auth,
                'profile':profile,
            }
            context.update({'userprofile':profile,'data':data})
        return  context

    def get_userprofile(self):
        return self.request.user.userprofile
```

La configuración de mi settings es la siguiente:

Tengo un settings llamado base.py en donde en relación a los archivos estáticos tengo lo siguiente (**No está la directiva de DEBUG en este settings/base.py**):

Generalmente aquí digo que mis archivos estáticos van a estar centralizados en un directorio llamado `static` gracias a la directiva de `STATIC_URL='/static/'`

Y después, con `STATICFILES_DIRS` estoy diciendo que busque los archivos estáticos dentro de un directorio llamado `static` así sea en cada aplicación o en la aplicación principal creada por Django al crear el proyecto.

```
# settings/base.py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# With this configuration, Django will look for static files in a folder named static inside each app and into the neurorehabilitation/static folder created.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Y tengo un settings llamado development.py que hereda de base.py y que posee esta configuración: **Nótese que tengo el** `DEBUG=TRUE` **en este settings/development.py**

He leído que el `DEBUG` debe estar en `False` cuando se quiere hacer cache de los archivos estáticos, aunque no sé si también cuando se quiere servirlos  desde el entorno de desarrollo.

También en este `settings/development.py` tengo una directiva llamada `MEDIA_ROOT` por medio de la cual le digo a Django que cuando yo suba un archivo, éste se guarde en un directorio llamado "media".

Y la directiva `MEDIA_URL` indica que los archivos (imágenes, sonido, video) van a servirse desde ese url `/media/`

```
# settings/development.py
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_env_variable('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': get_env_variable('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#Cuando suba los archivos de media (imagenes sonido, video), van a servirse
#desde ese url.    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2] + ['media'])
#Ahí le estamos diciendo que donde este, en la carpeta media, cree los
#elementos. Esto creara una carpeta media en el proyecto cuando subamos
#un archivo+
```

En mi plantilla `profile.html` estoy llamando la imagen por medio de la invocación del atributo photo el cual es un campo de tipo `ImageField`el cual va a la plantilla gracias a que en la vista anteriormente mostrada lo envió en el contexto.

Es dentro de la etiqueta `figure` cuando pretendo llamar la imagen de esta forma:

```
{% load static from staticfiles  %}
```

Acá todo el contenido de mi plantilla `profile.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!-- {% load staticfiles  %} -->
{% block content %}
    <div>
        {% if userprofile %}
            {{ userprofile.user.username }}, <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="">Login</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
            <div style="  ">
                <figure style=" ">
                    {% load static from staticfiles  %}
                    <img src="{% static '/media/{{ userprofile.user.photo }}' %}" alt="{{ userprofile.user.username }}">

                    <!-- <img src="/media/{{ userprofile.user.photo }}" alt="{{ userprofile.user.username }}"> -->

                    <figcaption>{{ userprofile.user.first_name }}</figcaption>
                    <!-- User esta relacionado 1 a 1 con userprofile model, por transitividad se llega
                     al campo username del modelo user desde userprofile-->
                </figure>

            </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Y es así como obtengo en mi navegador que la imagen no aparece, pero sí la información relacionada con el name y el username del usuario que recién inicia sesión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi log del servidor de Django obtengo esto:

```
[28/Dec/2015 08:14:58] "GET /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5467
Not Found: /media/{{ userprofile.user.photo }}
[28/Dec/2015 08:14:58] "GET /media/%7B%7B%20userprofile.user.photo%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 1885
```

Cuando llamo la imagen sin usar el tag `static` sino de la manera tradicional es decir de esta forma:

```
<img src="/media/{{ userprofile.user.photo }}" alt="{{ userprofile.user.username }}">
```

Ahí sí sale la imagen que quiero llamar.

¿Que configuración me puede estar faltando? O ¿qué puedo estar ignorando o pasando por alto?

De todas maneras algo que planeo hacer en un corto tiempo es centralizar mis archivos con `collectstatic` y ponerlos en un CDN tipo Amazon S3 o desde NGINX en un servidor. Pero por el momento en desarrollo quisiera trabajar con ellos así.

No sé qué puede estar faltándome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando quieres mostrar archivos subidos por los usuarios tienes que usar el atributo `url` del archivo, algo como esto:

```
<img src="{{ userprofile.user.photo.url }}" alt="{{ userprofile.user.username }}">
```

No confundas los `static` con los `media`, el primero sirve para tus archivos JavaScript, CSS, etc.; el segundo sirve para los archivos subidos por los usuarios. Dicho esto, no es necesario que uses `{% load static from staticfiles  %}`.

Si has definido correctamente la ruta en la que los archivos son subidos, no tiene sentido que uses `/media/` en la ruta, incluso si esto fuera correcto, estás yendo en contra de [DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas) ya que esto ya lo definiste en tu settings, lo correcto sería usar `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`.

Comment: Gracias. Tenía entendido que las imágenes también hacían parte de los archivos estáticos como se dice acá https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/ Aunque tal vez lo que quieras aclararme es que si si es asi, pero cuando se utiliza la directiva  MEDIA_URL no se usa el template tag static ... ¿?

Comment: Hay imágenes que son archivos estáticos, pienso yo, como el favicon por ejemplo, logos y demás. 
Pero en si videos, documentos, e imágenes creo que siempre van a parar a media.